# Symfony2 Doctrine - Many-To-Many where query

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

before anything, i tried the search function, but didnt find a thread about this one.
Heres my Problem. I'm using doctrine query builder with many-to-many relationship.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SOMEBUNDLE:INSERTION')->createQueryBuilder('insertion');
      $qb->select('
        insertion.id, 
        insertion.title, 
        insertion.content, 
        insertion.insertionpicture,
        insertion.timestamp,
        insertion.isanon,
        user.firstname as user_firstname, 
        user.lastname as user_lastname,
        user.picture as user_picture,
        supertag.name as supertag_name
        ');
      $qb->from('SOMEBUNDLE:USER', 'user');
      $qb->from('SOMEBUNDLE:SUPERTAG', 'supertag');
      $qb->from('SOMEBUNDLE:TAG', 'tag');
      $qb->andWhere('insertion.user = user.id');
      $qb->andWhere('insertion.supertag = supertag.id');
      $qb->andWhere("insertion.tag = :tag");
      $qb->setParameters('tag', $tags);
      return new JsonResponse($qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult());
```

Insertion.php

```
   /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $tag;
```

here in "andwhere(insertion.tag = :tag)" my parameter is an array. I got an invalid path expression exception because, I don't know how to set the parameters for a Doctrine collection.

THX

Comment: What is the `$tags` parameter, is it an array?

Comment: Yes something like: 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Fun"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Help"
}

Comment: Are they entities or the array only contains strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
$qb->andWhere("insertion.tag = :tag");
```

By this:

```
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->in('insertion.tag', $tags)
);
```

Anyway, you can reduce your code by chaining calls to the query builder:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('SOMEBUNDLE:INSERTION')
    ->createQueryBuilder('insertion');

$query = $qb
    # select only some columns from the tables
    ->select('partial insertion.{id, title, content, '.'
        insertionpicture, timestamp, isanon}, '.
        'partial user.{id, firstname, lastname, picture}, '.
        'partial supertag.{id, name} '
    )
    # if the Doctrine association is correct, joins are easy
    ->leftJoin('insertion.user', 'user')
    ->leftJoin('insertion.supertag', 'supertag')
    ->leftJoin('insertion.tag', 'tag')
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->in('tag.name', $tags)
    );

return new JsonResponse($query->getQuery()->getArrayResult());
```